# CSV file import to string and double

Tags: c++

I am trying to write my own investment software.  I am stuck on the best way to import my current data from a CSV file.  I can use either arrays or vector, but my current coding uses arrays.  The problem I have is a) cleaning up the code, b) getting the numbers to import as a number vice string.  Here is a snippet of my CSV file so you see what I am working with:

QRETQ,FDIC INSURED ACCOUNT - IRA,"6.000","$1.00","0.00(0.00%)","$0.00","N/A","$6.0"
IJJ,ISHARES S&P,"4.013","$147.70","0.56(0.38%)","$2.25","-$20.18","$592.67"

And code I have right now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string symbol[100];
string descrip[100];
string quantity[100];
string price[100];
string change[100];
string dayGainLoss[100];
string estGainLoss[100];
string marketBal[100];
string dividend[100];
string ph;


ifstream file ( "jroth.csv" );

    while ( file.good() )
    {
        for (int i=0; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            getline ( file, symbol[i], ',' );
            getline ( file, descrip[i], ',' );
            getline ( file,  ph, '"' );
            getline ( file, quantity[i], '"' );
            getline ( file,  ph, ',' );
            getline ( file,  ph, '"' );
            getline ( file,  ph, '$' );
            getline ( file, price[i], '"' );
            double buffer;
            buffer = stoi(price[i].data());
            getline ( file,  ph, ',' );
            getline ( file,  ph, '"' );
            getline ( file, change[i], '"' );
            getline ( file,  ph, ',' );
            getline ( file,  ph, '"' );
            getline ( file, dayGainLoss[i], '"' );
            getline ( file,  ph, ',' );
            getline ( file,  ph, '"' );
            getline ( file, estGainLoss[i], '"' );
            getline ( file,  ph, ',' );
            getline ( file,  ph, '"' );
            getline ( file,  ph, '$' );
            getline ( file, marketBal[i], '"' );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend using a structure to model the input line.  You can then have a container of these records.  A lot easier to  maintain than 9 arrays of strings.  You can also write *one* input method for the structure.

Comment: Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file csv" for a plethora of examples.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I plan to make this a struct long term.  For the moment, I am trying to make sure it is compiling properly.  It is pulling in everything right now, but only as a string.  Then every time I try and convert the numbers to a double, it gives me an error that it's not allowed.